# ¿Cómo validar un solo error en Zod?

Tags: reactjs, web, formularios, nextjs, zod

Tengo un schema en zod, en el que tengo distintas validaciones para un formulario.

¿Como podria incrustar en el JSX un solo error especifico?

```html
{errors.password && (
                <p">
                  <IconError />
                  {errors.password.message}
                </p>
              )}
```